# Prevent Windows From Creating New Network Names when Tethering with Android

Tags: windows-7, networking, android

How can I stop Windows 7 Home Premium from creating new network names each time I tether my Samsung Tablet to my Laptop using Androids USB Tethering Option?

Yesterday, it was Network 10. Each time I connect, it'll create a new name.

Can I have a single name when I connect using USB?

[image: New name each time]

Answer (score 19):

Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's answer only worked until I restarted my computer but this one works great.

You can try this if you don't mind the network icon not showing that you're connected.

1. Open Registry Editor (<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run dialog, then type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`.
3. There are numbered subkeys starting with 0001. Look in each subkey in descending order for the one with the DriverDesc value having your smartphone's RNDIS driver name (same name shown in your Network Connections view as the "Connect using" value).
4. Once located, create a new DWORD (32-bit) Value.
5. Enter the name as `*NdisDeviceType` (remember to include the asterisk sign * in front).
6. Edit the newly created DWORD value and enter the value data as `1` (Base choice doesn't matter). Click OK.
7. Once done, disable and re-enable usb tethering

You will no longer get a prompt asking for network location whenever you connect your smartphone, but you will still get the prompt when connecting to other devices.

Important Note: When you are only connected to your smartphone, your computer's network icon will continue to show that you are not connected to any network. However, the internet will still work fine.

Comment: This one still works as described on Windows 10, the other solutions are deprecated. An artful dodge!

Comment: This will disable any UWP app to connect to the internet, but only will allow desktop app to connect to the internet.

Comment: +1 to dns' comment. Especially, you won't be able to open MS Store anymore.

Comment: Will this work for only one phone/device or if I use different devices does it only settle one of the devices?

Comment: `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} /f DriverDesc  /s`

here cmd to help you find out in one second.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Network & Sharing Center
2. Change adapter settings
3. Right-click on your tethered "*Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device*"
4. Status
5. Details
6. Copy the IPv4 Address, Subnet Mask, Default Gateway & DNS Servers
7. Again Right-click on your tethered "Remote NDIS based Internet Sharing Device"
8. Properties
9. Highlight "*Internet protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)*"
10. Properties
11. For **Use the following IP address:** Enter what you copied earlier from *Status/Details* here
12. Click OK
13. Close all windows

[Source](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/96250-tethering-creates-a-new-network-every-time/page-2)

Answer (score 6):

I just live with it, but you can issue the following commands via `powershell` to clear all the networks list in the registry and restart from 0: after that, next time you tether, your network name will be "Network" (0), 1, 2, ...

```
Remove-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\"Windows NT"\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\* -Recurse
Remove-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\"Windows NT"\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged\* -Recurse
```

Comment: I tried these commands on Windows 10. It worked without restart but unplug and plug your usb tethering.

Comment: Here's the command prompt equivalent:
`@echo off
reg DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles" /va /f
reg DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged" /va /f`

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for this problem. It's quite simple. You have to just stop automatic proxy detection.

Start → Control Panel → Network and Internet → Internet Options → Connections → LAN Settings

Then uncheck automatic detect proxy and manual proxy both. Then Reset the pc and Boom.

Actually you don't need to detect IP on Windows when tethering because your set already has an IP address that may change according to your network provider and tethering just shares your mobile internet.

Notice: while using LAN internet check box auto detect proxy.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows 7 x64 Pro.