# How do I disable this networking dialog on Windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-8.1, android, tethering

When I tether my Android phone to Windows 8.1, I often get this useless dialog, which I always ignore. How do I prevent Windows 8.1 from showing it?

[image]

Comment: It's becuase it makes a new network each time you tether, so you have to answer that question.  See this (duplicate) question regarding that (for Windows 7): [Prevent Windows From Creating New Network Names when Tethering with Android](http://superuser.com/questions/729305/prevent-windows-from-creating-new-network-names-when-tethering-with-android)

Comment: Why do you consider this useless? It may be unwanted but it's not useless.

Comment: I thought it's a Win8-only problem, guess it happened on Win7 behind the scenes but I didn't notice it. The solution for Windows 7 worked on my machine, by the way.